# How to use nth-child correctly in html2pdf?

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I'm using html2pdf class to export a certain html page into pdf. The pdf is generated correctly with all styles applied successfully except for nth-child selector.

When I use the `tr:nth-child(even)` it displays perfectly in the plain html but doesn't appear in the pdf.

Any help how I can hack this html2pdf to accept my styles.